# Очереди по очереди по приоритетности в Laravel

Tags: laravel, очередь

Есть задача отправка заявок менеджерам по очереди, и логика выглядит так:

Залетает заявка она сохранилась в базу, и заношу её в очередь с приоритетностью low.

```
$job = ( new JobAblication($item, Auth::user()) )
            ->onQueue('low')
            ->onConnection('database');

        dispatch($job);
```

класс

```
class Application implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

public $application;
public $user;


/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($application, $user)
{
    $this->application = $application;
    $this->user = $user;
}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle(): void
{

    $queueHigh = DB::table('jobs')->where('queue', 'high')->exists();

    if ($queueHigh) {
        $this->release(15);
    } else {
        $job = ( new PushNotification($this->application, $this->user) )
            ->onQueue('high')
            ->onConnection('database');

        dispatch($job);

        return;
    }
}



public function failed(Exception $exception)
{
    Log::error(static::class . ' failed: ' . $exception->getMessage());
}
```

}

Дальше по коду я запускаю PushNotificatin очередь с приоритетностью high

Вопрос, можно как-то не обрабатывать приоритет low пока не уберутся полностью все приоритет high
даже если этих low собралось больше 10, пока есть high ничего не обрабатывать

я написал костыль `$queueHigh = DB::table('jobs')->where('queue', 'high')->exists();` который проверяет на наличие high, и удлиняет жизнь low если есть хоть один high, просто Job PushNotification может задержатся либо продолжать жизнь

Любая помощь будет оценена